# VBA Change Pivot filter and export pdf file

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automize a lot of my current excel work.
Atm i have about 30 filters in my pivottable that i need to change one at the time and then export as a pdf file. I was thinking it might be possible to create some VBA code that automatically changes the filter and exports a pdf (to a local folder) and then automatically moves on and changing next filter and create a pdf from that, and so on, 30 times.

I have tried to find some guide for it, but it has not been possible for me. Do you have any idea on how i can get started?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro covering a couple of iterations?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look into the two topics separately then combine.

1: Changing filters you could do via recording a macro then editing the results if you can't make sense of something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348319/set-filter-in-excel-with-vba).

2: Saving as pdf is a little trickier, as you could use many things to do it, depends if you have adobe on your machine etc or if you're using things like pdfcreator etc, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219784/vba-print-to-pdf-and-save-with-automatic-file-name) is an example where someone is doing something similar.

Give it a go and post your code back and people will be much more willing to try and help you.

Comment: I'll have to comment on this as I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer but in terms of what you have there, you could change the string after `Filename:=` to be dynamic, i.e. "C:\Users\username\Folder\Folder\Documents\Folder\Folder\Filename" & i & ".pdf" and increase i for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i found that i can Record a macro to:

1. Change filter
2. Save as PDF

which works perfectly, however i need the saved filename to be dynamic since i need 30 PDF files, and not 1.

The recorded code looks like this

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\username\Folder\Folder\Documents\Folder\Folder\Filename.pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Do you know how i then change the saved file name based on a cells name?